# R OSRM calculate travel distance within data.frame

Tags: r, r-sf

Using the osrm package, I want to calculate the distance between two points stored in two different columns of a data frame and put it into a new column.

Doing the following, however, does not work and throws the error: object 'lon' not found. What did go wrong here?

```
pacman::p_load(
  tidyverse,
  sf,
  osrm
)


test_1 <- data.frame(name_1 = c("a", "b"), long = c(13.371871012201932, 13.445856720780322), lat = c(52.5212875734526, 52.503693991115206)) %>%
    st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
    rename(geom_1 = "geometry")

test_2 <- data.frame(name_2 = c("c", "d"), long = c(13.401224766110927, 13.349212418670756), lat = c(52.51946945798967, 52.5149481833963)) %>%
    st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
    rename(geom_2 = "geometry")

comb <- expand_grid(test_1, test_2)


routes <- comb %>%
    mutate(distances = osrmRoute(
        src = geom_1,
        dst = geom_2,
        returnclass = "sf"
    )$distance)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that an `sf` object can only have one `geom` column active at a time. To get around this, just call the `sf` objects `test1` and `test2` and it should work.

Please find below the modified code and the corresponding output.

- Code

```r
routes <- comb %>%
  mutate(distances = osrmRoute(
    src = test_1,
    dst = test_2,
    returnclass = "sf"
  )$distance)
```

- Output:

```r
routes
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  name_1              geom_1 name_2              geom_2 distances
  <chr>          <POINT [°]> <chr>          <POINT [°]>     <dbl>
1 a      (13.37187 52.52129) c      (13.40122 52.51947)      4.35
2 a      (13.37187 52.52129) d      (13.34921 52.51495)      4.35
3 b      (13.44586 52.50369) c      (13.40122 52.51947)      4.35
4 b      (13.44586 52.50369) d      (13.34921 52.51495)      4.35
```

Alternatively, you can specify which `geom` column is active in your `sf` object `comb` and you will get the same result as above.

- Alternative code

```r
routes <- comb %>% mutate(distances = osrmRoute(
  src = st_sf(.,sf_column_name = "geom_1"),
  dst = st_sf(.,sf_column_name = "geom_2"),
  returnclass = "sf"
)$distance)
```

---

**EDIT**

As a follow-up to the exchanges I had with @Jindra Lacko (cf. comments below), I propose a `computeDistances()` function which can help you to get what you wish. Please find below the code of the function along with its output using your object `comb`

- Code of the function `computeDistances`

```r
computeDistances <- function(x){  
  
  distances <- data.frame(Distances = numeric())
  
  for (i in seq(x)){
    distances[i,"Distances"]  <- osrmRoute(
      src = st_sf(x,sf_column_name = "geom_1")[i,],
      dst = st_sf(x,sf_column_name = "geom_2")[i,],
      returnclass = "sf"
    )$distance
  }
  
  results <- st_sf(cbind(x, distances))
  
  return(results)
}
```

- Test of the function using your `comb` object

```
computeDistances(comb)

Simple feature collection with 4 features and 3 fields
Active geometry column: geom_1
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 13.37187 ymin: 52.50369 xmax: 13.44586 ymax: 52.52129
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
  name_1 name_2 Distances                    geom_1                    geom_2
1      a      c    4.3543 POINT (13.37187 52.52129) POINT (13.40122 52.51947)
2      a      d    2.6576 POINT (13.37187 52.52129) POINT (13.34921 52.51495)
3      b      c    4.4650 POINT (13.44586 52.50369) POINT (13.40122 52.51947)
4      b      d    8.1611 POINT (13.44586 52.50369) POINT (13.34921 52.51495)
```

Comment: I don't think this is a correct answer - see how the distance stays the same (4.35 km), despite the start and end points expected to change

Comment: Hello @Jindra Lacko. Yes, I have noticed what you have noticed yourself. But I'm waiting for the feedback of the OP because it's possibly a test data set where the points are equidistant. Anyway, if this is not the right solution I will delete my post.

Comment: Hi @lovalery, I have plotted the locations, and they have the look of four semi random locations in central Berlin. I strongly suspect that the `osrmRoute` call is not vectorized, and defaults to the first location pair (always). But having said that - please don't delete your answer, as you were correct in diagnosing the issue with invalid {sf} object (due to the two geometry columns). Which was the key question stated by the OP.

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback @Jindra Lacko. You are absolutely right: in fact the `distances` object created by the `osmRoutes()` function contains only one value (i.e. 4.35) which is recycled by the `mutate` function. As it is not vectorized, I think that the `osmRoutes()` function is not the appropriate tool for the purpose of the OP. I think the st_distance() function from the `sf` package would be the right solution.

Comment: Finally, I thank you for the second part of your comment and therefore keep my post which "technically" answers the request. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and sorry for replying late. Yes, this is because `osrmRoute` is not vectorized. As I did not find a quick workaround (and couldn't be bothered to write good loop for the rather large real data), I also resorted to simple arial distances calculated by `st_distance` which works with a two-geometry column sf object using `by_element = TRUE`. As this is fine for my purposes im satisfied with the answer. I would leave the Q open, tho, as there might be someone with a neat vectorization of osmRoutes() lying around in his codebase.

Comment: Hi @persephone, please find my edit above. I think (hope) this meets your needs. Also, two clarifications: (i) I think my suggestion to use `st_distance()` is not correct because this function computes the straight line distance between two points and not the shortest distance through the roads!!! Therefore, I think you should continue to use `osrmRoute()`,

Comment: (ii) I have used a `for` loop in my suggested function because I don't see any other solution except to modify the `osmRoute()` function itself so that it is vectorized. Actually, I think that for your needs, the function I propose should do the trick. If so, please consider marking this answer as accepted.

Comment: Last point! If you want the function to return a `dataframe` rather than an `sf` object, just replace the penultimate line of the function with the following code: `results <- cbind(x, distances)`. Cheers

Comment: Cheers! I have accepted your answer. I am aware st_distances gives airial distances. But it sufficed for a quick overview. Will adapt your suggestions later on. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer. I wish you the best in your work. Cheers.